# Multiple Intents on one ArrayList item

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, android-support-design

I have an ArrayList that contains details of a few hotels, what i want to do is on clicking at the address it opens up a map intent and on clicking on the phone number it opens up the phone.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
These are the code snippets.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, container, false);

    final ArrayList<pojo> pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<pojo>();
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_one), R.drawable.hotel_one, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_one_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid, getString(R.string.hotel_one_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_two), R.drawable.hotel_tow, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_two_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_two_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_three), R.drawable.hotel_three, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_three_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_three_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_four), R.drawable.hotel_four, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_four_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_four_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_five), R.drawable.hotel_five, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_five_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_five_phone)));

    HotelsAdapter adapter = new HotelsAdapter(getActivity(), pojoArrayList);
    ListView listViewItems = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            pojo pojo = pojoArrayList.get(position);

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31202246280"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 506 3715"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 2){
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 881 2595"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 665 1171"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 210 3535"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

And this is the layout for it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/hotel_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/hotel" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/grad"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_splash"
            android:alpha="0.4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:text="Hotels"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_layout"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/location_icon"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_map_" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_data"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hotel_one_location"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/phone_icon"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_solid" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone_data"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hotel_one_phone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter:

```
    public class HotelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pojo>{
    public HotelsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<pojo> pojo) {
        super(context, 0, pojo);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listView = convertView;
        if (listView == null){
            listView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hotel_items, parent, false);
        }
        pojo currentItem = getItem(position);

        ImageView backgroundImage = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        backgroundImage.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());

        TextView categoryHeader = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.category_header);
        categoryHeader.setText(currentItem.getHeaderResource());

        View categoryGradient  = (View) listView.findViewById(R.id.grad);
        categoryGradient.setBackgroundResource(currentItem.getGradientResource());

        ImageView locationIcon = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_icon);
        locationIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getLocationIconID());

        TextView addressView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_data);
        addressView.setText(currentItem.getAddressID());

        ImageView phoneIcon = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        phoneIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getPhoneIconID());

        TextView phoneView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_data);
        phoneView.setText(currentItem.getPhoneID());

        return listView;
    }
}
```

As of now I just have one intent that opens up the dialer. How would I select the location section and the phone section separately and have separate intents for both?

Comment: add your adapter file both layout and java

Comment: @ShubhamVala I've added the adapter.

Comment: @Tanveer already you got the pojo object in onItemClickListener then you can simplyfy the code to get phone value & respond create intent according to the layouts that is derived from the view arguments.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH could you please add an example? I'm kind of getting what you're saying but not entirely.

Comment: why dont u make separate click listener for both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class HotelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pojo> {
private Context mContext;

public HotelsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<pojo> pojo) {
    super(context, 0, pojo);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listView = convertView;
    if (listView == null) {
        listView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hotel_items, parent, false);
    }
    final pojo currentItem = getItem(position);

    ImageView backgroundImage = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
    backgroundImage.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());

    TextView categoryHeader = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.category_header);
    categoryHeader.setText(currentItem.getHeaderResource());

    View categoryGradient = (View) listView.findViewById(R.id.grad);
    categoryGradient.setBackgroundResource(currentItem.getGradientResource());

    ImageView locationIcon = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_icon);
    locationIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getLocationIconID());

    TextView addressView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_data);
    addressView.setText(currentItem.getAddressID());

    ImageView phoneIcon = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
    phoneIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getPhoneIconID());

    TextView phoneView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_data);
    phoneView.setText(currentItem.getPhoneID());

    // add this code in your adapter

    LinearLayout locationLayout = (LinearLayout) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_layout)
    locationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent geoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("geo:0,0?q=" + currentItem.getAddressID()));
            mContext.startActivity(geoIntent);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout phoneLayout = (LinearLayout) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_layout)
    locationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + currentItem.getPhoneID()));
            mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });


    return listView;
}
}
```

and remove listview.onitemClicklistener();

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really grateful that you took the time to answer this. You're code is working without any issues.

Comment: This follows bad separation of concern. These events should be handled by your Activity or Fragment, and not by your Adapter.

What would happen if you needed to make a UI change or add something that was kept in the Activity to the intent? Then your method won't work

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> **First i suggest to use Recylerview because Recylerview is the advanced one**.

Check Here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView

```
listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        pojo pojo = pojoArrayList.get(position);

        LinearLayout linear_phone = view.findViewById(R.id.phone_layout);
        linear_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(pojo.getPhoneID()));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });

     LinearLayout linear_location = view.findViewById(R.id.location_layout);
        linear_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             //Location Intent Code

        }
    });


    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I get it now. What you were trying to say was similar to what @Shubham answered above. With his answer the code can be used in other lists as well.

Comment: Welcome glad to help..!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your entire list-item to be clickable, but rather have clickable elements inside of your list, you should implement a custom listener

Create a listener interface, specifying a method for each individual subview that should be clickable, implement it in your Activity/Fragment, and then pass it to your custom list adapter.

Your custom adapter will then call the listener's methods depending on which field is clicked.

**Example Interface**

```
public interface HotelListClickListener {
    void onAddressClicked(Pojo item);
    void onPhoneClicked(Pojo item);
    ...
}
```

You should then modify your HotelsAdapter to receive the listener at some point (Constructor, or Setter), and then call each appropriate method in your **getView** method.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    Pojo currentItem = getItem(position);

    TextView addressView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.location_data);
    addressView.setText(currentItem.getAddressID());
    addressView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listener != null)
                listener.onAddressClicked(currentItem);
        }
    });

    TextView phoneView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.phone_data);
    phoneView.setText(currentItem.getPhoneID());
    phoneView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listener != null)
                listener.onPhoneClicked(currentItem);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

And then finally, in your Activity/Fragment you would create a global listener that will receive the appropriate POJO when a specific child view is clicked, and then handle whichever element was clicked.

```
HotelListClickListener listener = new HotelListClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAddressClicked(Pojo item) {
        // Show map view based on item's address
    }
    @Override
    public void onPhoneClicked(Pojo item) {
        // Call number of item that was clicked
    }
};

HotelsAdapter adapter = new HotelsAdapter(getActivity(), pojoArrayList, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

add View.Onclicklistener for phoneView and addressView

```
public class HotelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pojo>{
    public HotelsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<pojo> pojo) {
        super(context, 0, pojo);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        /****your code*****/

        //add listener
        addressView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        phoneView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        return listView;
    }
    //add View.Onclicklistener for phoneView and addressView
    private OnClickListener mClickListener;
    public void setOptionClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        this.mClickListener = listener;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, container, false);

    final ArrayList<pojo> pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<pojo>();
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_one), R.drawable.hotel_one, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_one_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid, getString(R.string.hotel_one_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_two), R.drawable.hotel_tow, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_two_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_two_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_three), R.drawable.hotel_three, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_three_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_three_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_four), R.drawable.hotel_four, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_four_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_four_phone)));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo(getString(R.string.hotel_five), R.drawable.hotel_five, R.drawable.gradient_splash, R.drawable.ic_map_, getString(R.string.hotel_five_location), R.drawable.ic_phone_solid,getString(R.string.hotel_five_phone)));

    HotelsAdapter adapter = new HotelsAdapter(getActivity(), pojoArrayList);
    ListView listViewItems = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    //when you click list's item
    pojo currentTarget;
    listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            pojo pojo = pojoArrayList.get(position);
            currentTarget = pojo
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31202246280"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 506 3715"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 2){
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 881 2595"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 665 1171"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: +31 20 210 3535"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    });
    adapter.setOptionClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.location_data:
                    //TODO: currentTarget's data that opens up a map
                    break;
                case R.id.phone_data:
                    //TODO: currentTarget's data that opens up the phone 
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```